# Extending $f(p^k)$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: prime-numbers, functional-equations

If we have a function $f(x)$, for which we know that $f(p^k)=(p^s+1)^k p^{sk}$ where $p$ is prime, $k$ is a real number, and $s$ is a constant, how do we find $f(x)$? My try: let $k=\log_p(x)$, so that no matter what $p$ is, $p^k$ is constant equal to $x$. Plugging this in to the other side of the equation, we have $$f(p^{\log_p(x)})=(p^s+1)^{\log_p(x)}p^{s\log_p(x)}$$ $$=x^{\log_p(p^s+1)}x^s$$ $$=x^{\log_p(p^s+1)+s}$$. The only problem with this is that this side of the equation is *not* constant if $p$ changes, e.g. $x^{\log_2(2^s+1)+s}\not=x^{\log_3(3^s+1)+s}$, while on the other side it was a constant expression (see above). This seems to be a problem, and I can't find the error.

Suggestions?

Comment: One solution is that your functional equation can yield a set of functions as solutions, each one being a different branch that corresponds to a particular value of p

Comment: It could--and it appears to--but I don't understand why if, on one side of the equation, we have a constant expression (relative to $p$) and on the other side we have a varying expression. I'm changing the question to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a "simpler" version of your functional equation where $p$ can be any sort of number

In that case:

$$f(p^k) = {\lbrace(  (p^s + 1)p^s \rbrace)}^k$$

That reduces to:

$$f(p^k) = f(p)^k$$

So now we have :

$$f(p) = (p^s + 1)p^s $$

Note here that if we consider $f(p^k)$it then must be true that:

$$(p^{sk}+ 1)p^{sk} = ((p^s + 1)p^s)^k $$

This is clearly not true for all $p,k$ for any given $s$ and therefore we immediately conclude the real number version of your functional equation has no global solution for all real numbers.

This argument can now be modified to consider prime numbers and real exponents to again show the original problem has no solution.

Comment: I don't understand how you get to $(p^{sk} + 1)p^{sk} = ((p^s + 1)p^s)^k$. As far as I can see it should be $(p^s + 1)^k p^{sk} = ((p^s + 1)p^s)^k$. Moreover, I have very little background in functional equations, and don't follow how either this version or your version implies that there is no solution. Could you either edit your answer or comment to elucidate?

Comment: Actually that is correct, the reason being that p^k should be substituted for p itself, if we are evaluating $p^k$ and we should naturally see the $k$ rise to the top of the exponent and outside the base. Since our functional equation basically implies exactly that. Follow each line of my argument carefully to see why this is true

Comment: Ah, I see. You are indeed correct. However, I still don't see how you would make a similar argument with the restriction of $p \in \mathbb P$, since given this restriction you can't execute the step of substituting $p^k$ for $p$, which I believe is necessary to the proof.

Comment: Find a prime number P, and a real k for which this is not true. A single counterexample is all you need. (Try for example: 3, and e as the prime and k respectively). We are still allowed to substitute $p^k$ only this time when finding a counter example, $p$ must be prime.

Comment: Not to continue the discussion beyond its reasonable limits, but what if we require $k$ to be an integer, so that $p^k$ and $p$ cannot both be prime? (This is a condition of the original problem that I had left out to simplify the situation.)

Comment: @Laertes It is fine to discuss to like this, as long as the discussion is relevant to the problem and constructive :). To address your point we still have the same issue (try for example 3: and 6) the issue isn't your choice of domain and range. The problem is that the definition of the function itself is killing it since the expression $f(p,k)$ can be transformed into $G(H(P,s), k)$ (watch the parenthesis carefully) and therefore we can always recover that $f(p,1) = f(p) = G(H(p,s)) = something \ in \ our \ case \ (p^s + 1)p^s$

Comment: Thanks, I finally get it. Will accept and upvote.